# Array match and return response

Tags: arrays, ruby, match

I'm really stuck on this thing..

I'm having **RESPONSE** table with ***answer*** and ***question[array]*** field and what I'm trying to do is, if I gonna type 'HI' its gonna loop trough all responses array in question field, find a match and it should return an answer or `id` of response to get the answer.

`#<Response id: 3, answer: "Hi, there!", question: ["hi", "hello", "sup"]>`

and the output should be `id` if the question is matching or an `answer` if i type one of the following inputs in array

```
Response.all.each do |r|
  r.include? "hi"
end
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you have, and and the desired output (as well as what in particular you are having trouble with).

Comment: @Damon: Example added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there! This should work :

```
response = Response.find do |r|
  r.question.include? "hi"
end
```

If you want the answer :

```
response.answer
```

after having checked that `response` isn't `nil`.

If you use Ruby 2.3, you can use

```
response&.answer
```

Notes:

- You're using Rails, right? If you give more info (table structure, database 
  type, ...) it would probably be possible to achieve a more performant query.
- It's a convention in Ruby to name an Array with a plural. `question` is just one question (String), `questions` would be a list of questions (an Array of Strings).
- It might be a good idea to save all the questions in lowercase : `['Hi', 'Hello'].include? 'hi' #=> false`

Comment: so then if i wanna get if i can say `if r.question.include? "hi" puts r.answer end` id i gonna get answer for the current match right?

Comment: See update. `find` returns the first element found for which the block is true. You'd use `response.answer` after the block.